Decidability - "they are distinct extended lambdas" error
I was doing some examples for the Any? predicate that decides whether any element of a list satisfies the predicate:
Any? P? (x :: xs) with P? x   | Any? P? xs
...                   | yes Px      |     _         =   yes (here Px)
...                   |     _       |    yes Pxs    =   yes (there Pxs)
...                   | no ¬Px      |  no ¬AnyPxs   =   no (λ {(here Px) → ¬Px Px ; (there Pxs) → ¬AnyPxs Pxs})

I was trying this using the predicate "n is even"
Decide-N-Even : ∀ (n : ℕ) → Dec (even n)
Decide-N-Even 0 = yes zero
Decide-N-Even (suc n) with Decide-N-Even n
...                      | no ¬EvenN = yes (suc (¬-even→odd n ¬EvenN))
...                      | yes evenN = no (λ {(suc OddN) → (even→¬odd n evenN) OddN})

I would like to show that Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 ] is of course, a "no", since the list [ 5 ] doesnt contain even numbers. The problem is that this solution doesnt work:
_ : (Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 ]) ≡ no (λ { (here 5IsEven) → ¬5Even 5IsEven})
_ = refl

where ¬5Even is a proof that 5 is not even
¬5Even : ¬ (even 5)
¬5Even 5IsEven = (even→¬odd 5 5IsEven) (suc (suc (suc (suc (suc zero)))))

I tried a similar exercise with a "yes":
_ : Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 , 4 , 3 ] ≡ yes (there (here (suc (suc (suc (suc zero))))))
_ = refl

and it worked.
Im not sure how to prove
_ : (Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 ]) ≡ no (λ { (here 5IsEven) → ¬5Even 5IsEven})

or even if it's true (I think it should be). I tried using a helper function to pass the induction steps:
t = helper (Decide-N-Even 5) (Any? (Decide-N-Even) []) where
    postulate helper : (Dec (even 5)) → (Dec (Any even [])) → (Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 ]) ≡ no (λ { (here 5IsEven) → ¬5Even 5IsEven})

but is causing the following error:
(λ { (here 5IsEven) → ¬5Even 5IsEven ; (there ()) }) x !=
(λ { (here 5IsEven) → ¬5Even 5IsEven ; (there ()) }) x of type ⊥
Because they are distinct extended lambdas: one is defined at

   Lists10.agda:1101,91-127
and the other at
   Lists10.agda:1099,38-74,
so they have different internal representations.
when checking that the inferred type of an application
  Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 ] ≡
  no (λ { (here 5IsEven) → ¬5Even 5IsEven ; (there ()) })
matches the expected type
  Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 ] ≡
  no (λ { (here 5IsEven) → ¬5Even 5IsEven ; (there ()) })

The error seems weird because the two lambdas look identical. So Im not really sure how to approach what should be relatively easy, prove that (Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 ]) is a "no".

Cf. https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/curly-braces-and-lambdas-in-agda

Does _ : (Any? Decide-N-Even [ 5 ]) ≡ no _; _ = refl work? It'd be easier to help you if included full code.

The yes case works because even computes to refl or tt (not sure which even you are using) and every refl and tt are the same. But the no case does not compute to ¬5Even. You will have the same difficulty proving (p : ¬ (even 5)) ->  p ≡ ¬5Even for example, because there are different ways to show that 5 is not even, so not every proof that 5 is even. Your postulate does not compute despite "looking" the same, but that is a different problem, since in the first example, the proofs are definitely not the same. You probably want to prove ∃ (λ p -> Any? ... ≡ no p) instead
